# ReactJS: "Unexpected end of JSON input"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting an `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` error when I reload my side.

This is my code:

```
const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");

const onSubmitHandler = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let result = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/register", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ name, email }),
  });
  result = await result.json();
  console.warn(result);
  if (result) {
    alert("Data saved succesfully");
    setName("");
    setEmail("");
  }
};
```

I'm pretty new to APIs and completely new to dbs and I can't figure out what is wrong with my JSON rendering.

How do I solve this?

Edit: My working environment is: node as backend, react as frontend and mongodb as database with mongoose for connection.

Edit 2: My server part

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

mongoose
  .connect(url)
  .then("Database connceted")
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

const User = mongoose.model("users", userSchema);
User.createIndexes();

app.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = new User(req.body);
    let result = await user.save();
    result = result.toObject();
    if (result) {
      delete result.password;
      res.send(req.body);
      console.log(result);
    } else {
      console.log("User already registered");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.send("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you post your server-side response from the `register` route?

Comment: Theses kind of error message appears when something wrong on server-side response,like wrong json structure / its not even JSON response.Please post the API response or check it properly as @jQueeny suggested